# Blender to Unity preview rotation

Tags: rotation, blender, preview, unity-game-engine

When I import a model made in Blender to Unity the preview image rotates, when I drag it into the editor it's rotation is fine. It only happens though when the model consists more objects and I join them with CTRL+J in Blender. Let me show an example. I made this house in a few clicks, for the "seperated" one I left the roof as an individual object and for the "joined" one I hit CTRL+J so that they became one object. [Here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyWEm.png) The "seperated" shows up fine while the "joined" rotates in the preview. I tried to import it straight to Unity as a blend file and also exported it as an fbx from Blender but the result is the same. For more complex models which consists of a lot of objects I like to join them so they appear as one mesh. I haven't find any fix for this, I hope someone can help. I use Unity 5.3.2 and Blender 2.76b.

Comment: I think this question is better placed [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't noticed that the up axis for Unity and Blender is different.
In Unity it is 'Y' and in Blender it is 'Z'.
So when you import any model from Blender Unity sets Rotation x = 90.
It's not a big deal, just group it to fix it.

Comment: I know about the up axis being different in Blender and Unity, in the scene and game panel the models appear as they should, they only appear rotated in the preview. Though if the individual parts of a model are not joined in Blender then they appear right both in the preview and in the scene. The rotation only occurs in Unity's preview when I join several parts into one mesh in Blender.

Comment: What I have found is that when I have multiple objects in a blender scene, unity makes a group with the scene name and puts the objects inside with rotation x being 90. And when I have only a single object, there is no group and the rotation x is 90. The preview is rotated. Is your gameobject in the scene view is rotated as well when you drag the model from the project pane?

Comment: It's only rotated in the preview, in the scene and game view it's correct.

Comment: That is how things are I am afraid. It's all due to up axis differences.